# Improve the wording of the “not reproducible” custom close reason

Tags: feature-request, meta, wording, custom-close-reasons

On Meta SE, there is a custom close reason

> The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

Right now, this close reason seems to be mainly used for feature requests or bugs concerning a feature that has been changed entirely or removed. However, the only part of its wording that entirely fits this purpose is: “Changes to the system […] have rendered it obsolete.” Everything else seems to be worded with an unreproducible bug in mind. Thus, I always hesitate a little when selecting it to close such a question.

On the other hand, this close reason is rarely used for actual unreproducible bugs. The most recent question with [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) closed with this reason is more than four months old, unless I missed some roomba-deleted question ([relevant search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bstatus-norepro%5d%20closed%3ayes%20duplicate%3ano)). So, this does not really seem to be needed anymore.

Can we change the above close reason to better include obsolete problems or focus on them?

Answer (score 4):

I would drop the obsolete-bug aspect entirely and suggest the following wording:

> Changes to the system, policies or similar have rendered this question **obsolete**. If you have a similar question, please ask it separately.